# error: mscorlib.dll assembly is not found during C++ and C# compile

Tags: c#, c++

Similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552951/statically-linking-a-c-library-to-a-c-sharp-process-using-cli-or-any-other-way), I have MS VC 2013 Express and successfully installed .Net framework. I have a solution with code mixed between c++ and c# (with managed code enabled.)

I want to create a static library from my code. Now I can create a dynamic library without any problem, but I get this error message during compiling my code:

```
fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'mscorlib.dll': please
specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH
environment variable
```

I added the lib and its path by hand, and all other options suggested by MS pages, but there is still no solution.

**My questions:**

Can even I have static lib with mixed code? How I can create static lib only from my C++ code which uses C# code?

(Furthermore, when I change from x86 to x64 in the project properties the *Linker* menu changes to *Librarian*, why?)

EDIT:
Finally I could solve this issue. First of all I also think to create only pure static lib is not possible. I changed to dynamic lib. As soon as I have more clarified info considering my question I write here.

Comment: thanks the edit suggestion

Comment: Static libraries with mixed mode code are not supported.  You cannot make this work, you must create a DLL.

Comment: And cannot even I creating lib only for the wrapper (C++) part? I don't want to static link the C# code as it is not possible indeed.

Comment: Linking a static library that contains *only* native C++ code, none of it compiled with /clr in effect, is not a problem.